# How to hide the header from Tab navigation (bottom-tabs) in react navigation 5.x?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i am trying to use createBottomTabNavigator function for create bottom navigation tab, i want to hide the 
  header, bellow the screenshot:

[image]

I have a BottomTabNavigator inside a stackNavigator bellow the code:
This is the rooter configuration file rooter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WelcomeScreen from '../component/WelcomeScreen';
import Login from '../component/login/Login';
import Register from '../component/register/Register';
import RegisterTwo from '../component/register/RegisterTwo';
import TabsBottom from '../component/tabs/TabsNavigation'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  const AppSwitchNavigator = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator  initialRouteName="WelcomeScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="TabsBottom" component={TabsBottom} />
          <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          <Stack.Screen name="RegisterTwo" component={RegisterTwo} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  export const AppContainer = AppSwitchNavigator;
```

This is my nested navigator TabsNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Explore from '../Explore';
import Settings from '../Settings';
import Profile from '../Profile';
import Search from '../Search';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import colors from '../../../styles/colors/index';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName;
        if (route.name === 'Explore') {
          iconName = focused ? 'home': 'home';
          color = focused ? colors.mainColor : colors.gray03;
        } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'cog' : 'cog';
          color = focused ? colors.mainColor : colors.gray03;
        }
        else if (route.name === 'Search') {
          iconName = focused ? 'search' : 'search';
          color = focused ? colors.mainColor : colors.gray03;
        }
        else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
          iconName = focused ? 'user-alt' : 'user-alt';
          color = focused ? colors.mainColor : colors.gray03;
        }
        return <Icon name={iconName} size={30} color={color} />;
      }    
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: colors.mainColor,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.gray03
    }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={Explore} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
export default function TabsBottom() {
  return (
      <MyTabs />  
  );
}
```

I want delete the screen's headres 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 44):

From version 6.x.x

You just need to add

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}> 

or

<HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
```

and it will hide the header

Answer (score 8):

For the latest version in React Native:

If you want to remove the header for all bottom tabs, use this prompt:

```
<TabNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}/>
```

Or, if you want to remove it for a particular bottomTabScreen, use this:

```
<TabNavigator.Screen name="home" component={HomeStack} />
```

Answer (score 5):

Use following line. Write `headerShown` as *false*. It will remove header:

```
<Stack.Screen name="TabsBottom" options={{headerShown: false}} component={TabsBottom} />
```

Answer (score 4):

To hide the 'Tabs Bottom' header you have to add a `headerShown: false` option to your TabsBottom `Stack.Screen` component like this:

```html
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  const AppSwitchNavigator = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator  initialRouteName="WelcomeScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="TabsBottom" component={TabsBottom} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          <Stack.Screen name="RegisterTwo" component={RegisterTwo} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  export const AppContainer = AppSwitchNavigator;
```

Answer (score 2):

(React Nav ver6.x) add this code snipet "**options={{headerShown: false}}**" in "**<Tab.Screen />**".It will delete header of each tab you add into.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at react-native stuff but the [documentation about hiding tab bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens)
 says that, in nested navigator (tabNavigator inside stackNavigator in the doc), you have to put your screen in the parent navigator, which make sense since each navigator handle their own screen.

If I refer to your screen, you have a stackNavigator and a tabNavigator, so just apply this principle. If you still need help, please provide a repro (A Snack expo would be appreciated, or just paste your full code in your question) so we can work on it.

Comment: thanks you for your responsiveness, what I want is to remove the header from the tabNavigation screens see the screenshot

Comment: @fullstackdeveloper Your tabNavigator needs to be above your stackNavigator then. This way the stackNavigator header won't appear for the routes that are handled by the tabNavigator.